# Deployment of Django project on Railway using Nixpacks

Tags: django, deployment, nix, railway, nixpkgs

Has anyone know about step by step process how to deploy Django project on Railway using **Nixpacks**? I really mean **easy to follow step by step** guide follow up my first steps. I am using Windows 10:

1. Django project created with apps tested locally at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
2. Django project uploaded on github
3. ...
   .
   .
   .

Comment: Did you check [this](https://devpress.csdn.net/postgresql/62f233d3c6770329307f6268.html)

Comment: @AdamuDeeAzare I could not figure out the correct process, but found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wczWm8j4v9w which works great and already deployed successfully on render.com instead of railway

Comment: I have decided to use render.com instead, as it is much more straight forward, but keep this question opened, as it may benefit others.

Comment: Well, Well, Well, that's good for you.